# Rosalind string algorithm problems

Tags: beginner, algorithm, strings, bioinformatics, rust

I've been starting to learn Rust by going through some of the [Rosalind String Algorithm problems](http://rosalind.info/problems/topics/string-algorithms/).

If anyone would like to point out possible improvements, or anything else, that would be great. There are a couple of things I'm especially curious about noted in the subs and lcsm solutions.

main.rs:

```
mod utils;
mod string_algorithms;

fn main() {

    //string_algorithms::dna();
    //string_algorithms::rna();
    //string_algorithms::revc();
    //string_algorithms::gc();
    //string_algorithms::subs();
    string_algorithms::lcsm();

    println!("done!");
}
```

utils.rs:

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use std::fs::File;

pub fn read_file(abbr: &str) -> String {

    let name = "Input/rosalind_".to_string() + abbr + ".txt";

    let mut input = String::new();

    File::open(name)
        .unwrap()
        .read_to_string(&mut input)
        .unwrap();

    input
}

use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::char;

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub fn read_fasta(abbr: &str) -> BTreeMap<String, String> {

    let input = read_file(abbr);

    // read format:
    // >NAME\n
    // STRBLAHBLAHBLAH\n
    // STILLTHESAMESTR\n
    // >NAME\n
    // ...

    let mut result = BTreeMap::new();

    for x in input.split('>').skip(1) {

        let mut iter = x.split(char::is_whitespace);

        let name = iter.next().unwrap().to_string();
        let dna = iter.collect::<String>();

        result.insert(name, dna);
    }

    result
}

pub fn write_file(abbr: &str, output: &str) {

    let name = "Output/rosalind_".to_string() + abbr + ".txt";

    File::create(name)
        .unwrap()
        .write(output.as_bytes())
        .unwrap();
}
```

string_algorithms.rs:

```
use utils;

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub fn dna() {

    // Read DNA string from file and count A, C, G, T characters.
    // Is there a way to do this without the Counter class?

    let abbr = "dna";

    let input = utils::read_file(abbr);

    struct Counter {
        a: u32, c: u32, g: u32, t: u32,
    }

    impl Counter {
        fn new() -> Counter {
            Counter{
                a: 0u32, c: 0u32, g: 0u32, t: 0u32,
            }
        }
    }

    let count = input.chars().fold(Counter::new(), |mut total, ch| {
            total.a += (ch == 'A') as u32;
            total.c += (ch == 'C') as u32;
            total.g += (ch == 'G') as u32;
            total.t += (ch == 'T') as u32;

            total
        });

    let output = format!("{} {} {} {}", count.a, count.c, count.g, count.t);

    println!("{}", output);

    utils::write_file(abbr, &output);
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub fn rna() {

    // Read DNA string from file and replace all T characters with U.
    // (Easy enough...)

    let abbr = "rna";

    let input = utils::read_file(abbr);

    let output = input.replace("T", "U");

    println!("{}", output);

    utils::write_file(abbr, &output);
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub fn revc() {

    // Read DNA string from file, reverse it, then swap A with T and C with G.

    let abbr = "revc";

    let input = utils::read_file(abbr);

    let output : String = input.chars().rev().map(|mut ch| {
            if ch == 'A' { ch = 'T'; }
            else if ch == 'T' { ch = 'A'; }
            else if ch == 'C' { ch = 'G'; }
            else if ch == 'G' { ch = 'C'; }
            ch
        }).collect();

    println!("{}", output);

    utils::write_file(abbr, &output);
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub fn gc() {

    // Read Name / DNA String pairs from file...
    // Find string with highest percentage of C and G.

    let abbr = "gc";

    let input = utils::read_fasta(abbr);

    let mut max = ("", 0f32);

    for (k, v) in input.iter() {

        let gc_count = v.chars().filter(|&ch| ch == 'G' || ch == 'C').count();
        let gc_percent = 100f32 * gc_count as f32 / v.len() as f32;

        if gc_percent > max.1 {
            max = (&k, gc_percent);
        }
    }

    let output = format!("{} {}", max.0, max.1);

    println!("{}", output);

    utils::write_file(abbr, &output);
}

use std::char;

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub fn subs() {

    // Read string and substring from file.
    // Count the number of occurrences of the substring in the whole string
    // (including overlapping matches!).

    let abbr = "subs";

    let input = utils::read_file(abbr);

    // Extract whole and substring from file format: "wholestring\nsubstring"

    let mut iter = input.split(char::is_whitespace);

    let whole = iter.next().unwrap().to_string();
    let sub = iter.collect::<String>(); // Why doesn't next.unwrap().to_string() work here too?

    assert!(!whole.is_empty());
    assert!(!sub.is_empty());
    assert!(whole.len() >= sub.len());

    let mut positions = Vec::<usize>::new();

    for i in 0..((whole.len() - sub.len()) + 1) {

        let m = whole.chars().skip(i)
            .zip(sub.chars())
            .all(|(w, s)| w == s);

        if m {
            positions.push(i + 1);
        }
    }

    let output = positions.iter()
        .map(|p| p.to_string())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .join(" ");

    println!("{}", output);

    utils::write_file(abbr, &output);
}

pub fn lcsm() {

    // Read Name / DNA string pairs from file.
    // Find the longest substring present in all the strings.

    // Work through all substrings of the first string (starting with the longest),
    // and check if it's present in all the other strings too.

    // (Could sort the strings so the shortest is first,
    // but they're all about the same length so it makes no difference...)

    let abbr = "lcsm";

    let input = utils::read_fasta(abbr);

    let first: &String = input.values().next().unwrap();

    for length in (1..(first.len() + 1)).rev() {

        let mut start = 0;

        loop {

            let end = start + length;

            // BAD: This copies the string... how to avoid this?
            let sub = first.chars().skip(start).take(length).collect::<String>();

            if input.values().skip(1).all(|x| x.contains(&sub)) {

                println!("{}", sub);

                utils::write_file(abbr, &sub);

                return;
            }

            if end == first.len() {
                break;
            }

            start += 1;
        }
    }

    assert!(false);
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Vogel612 My bad. I've added it as an answer instead, I hope that's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am new to rust as well it may not be the best alternative but I got a small suggestion that I think its better than what you got.

In this particular part:

```
let output : String = input.chars().rev().map(|mut ch| {
            if ch == 'A' { ch = 'T'; }
            else if ch == 'T' { ch = 'A'; }
            else if ch == 'C' { ch = 'G'; }
            else if ch == 'G' { ch = 'C'; }
            ch
}).collect();
```

you could change it to this (taking advantage that almost everything is an expression):

```
let output : String = input.chars().rev().map(|ch| {
             match ch {
                 'A' => 'T',
                 'T' => 'A',
                 'C' => 'G',
                 'G' => 'C',
                  _  => ch
             }
}).collect();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly an improvement. I've also changed the dna() function to use `match` when counting characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using MAG's suggestion, I've also improved the "dna" solution like so:

```
let (mut a, mut c, mut g, mut t) = (0u32, 0u32, 0u32, 0u32);

for ch in input.chars() {
    match ch {
        'A' => a += 1,
        'C' => c += 1,
        'G' => g += 1,
        'T' => t += t,
        _ => (),
    };
}
```